# Google Closure: working equation editor demo?

Tags: google-closure

### Context

I am aware of http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/equationeditor.html#

However, when I try it, it does not work for me.

### Question:

Is there a working demo of the Google Closure equation editor? I know it probably works since it works inside of Google Docs, however, I can't find sample code to see how to use the EquationEditor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the source files, you'll see that many library references are hardcoded like

`goog.ui.equation.ImageRenderer.SERVER_NAME_ = 'https://www.google.com';`

It looks like you have to copy-paste quite a bit of coded if you want to use this without depending on google, or if you want to customize the behavior. Basic usage is very simple:

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/equationeditor.js